# Implement download in a Flask application

Tags: python, flask, download, flask-wtforms

I'm a beginner of Python/Flask programming and I'm having some problems with the implementation of the "download function" in my Flask Application.

I have created a table with Flask-Table where I've put my materials from database. And until now, it's all ok.
Here, there is my code:

```
def get_table(number):

items = Material.query.filter_by(university_id = number)

class ItemTable(Table):
    author = Col('Author')
    title = Col('Title')
    subject = Col('Subject')
    description = Col('Description')
    university_id = Col('Faculty')
    professor = Col('Professor')
    rating = Col('Rating')
    download = ButtonCol('Download','download')

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, author,title,subject,description,university_id,professor,rating,download):
        self.author = author
        self.title = title
        self.subject = subject
        self.description = description
        self.university_id = university_id
        self.professor = professor
        self.rating = rating
        self.download = items.link

table = ItemTable(items)
return table
```

This is my class Material :

```
class Material(Base):
__tablename__ = 'material'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
title = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
link = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
author = Column(String(20), ForeignKey('user.username'), nullable=False)
university_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('university.id'), nullable=False)
professor = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
subject = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
rating = Column(Enum('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'))

def __init__(self, id, title, link, author, university_id, professor, subject, description, rating):
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.link = link
    self.author = author
    self.university_id = university_id
    self.professor = professor
    self.subject = subject
    self.description = description
    self.rating = rating
```

Then I've tried to put a ButtonCol in my "ItemTable Class" because I'd like to have a button for all the materials and give users the possibility to download them.
But honestly, I don't know to go on.
I have implemented the upload function and I've saved the URL of materials uploaded in the DB but I don't really know how I can take this link from DB and download the file clicked by the user.
I've thought also for a form inside the table, so I can send with a "submit" the link of file and create a download function, but with Flask-Table I can't put a form inside a table.

Here there is the code of my upload function:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():

form1 = MaterialForm(csrf_enabled=False)
form2 = UploadForm(csrf_enabled=False)

file = request.files['doc']
if form2.validate_on_submit():

    title = request.form['title']
    author = request.form['author']
    university = request.form['university']
    professor = request.form['professor']
    subject = request.form['subject']
    description= request.form['description']

    uniid = applicativo.get_id_by_uni(university)
    last = Material.query.order_by(Material.id.desc()).first()
    num = (last.get_id() + 1)

    newrow = Material(
                id = num,
                title = title,
                link= file,
                author = author,
                university_id = uniid,
                professor= professor,
                subject = subject,
                description = description,
                rating = ''
                    )

    db.session.add(newrow)
    db.session.commit()

    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                            filename=filename))
```

I hope you can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically whenever a user clicks on the "Download" button you should take the file as binary data from the database. If it is not a binary data you can convert it and then you have to make a response with custom headers related to the file MIME type so the browser should know how to treat it on the response, to start a download procedure for example.
You can take a look at this example as some reference to start with: http://code.runnable.com/UiIdhKohv5JQAAB6/how-to-download-a-file-generated-on-the-fly-in-flask-for-python

Once you implement the basic download for one file you can use custom routing to download different files from the database.

Your route can be something like:

```
@app.route("/download/<filename>")
def download(filename):
    #get the file from the database depending on the filename
    #once you have the file convert it to binary data if it is not, but usually it should be.
    #configure the correct "Content-Type" headers
    #usually the headers "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
    # and Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.txt" should be ok for the browser to start the downloader
    #make the response with the binary data and the headers included
```

This is post from the official docs on how to stream document which basically should do the described above: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I've only a problem: I don't know how to take this <filename> if I don't have a form with a submit that send the link of material.
And implementing HTML table with Flask-Table doesn't allow me to insert a form in the table as I could do with HTML5

Comment: Once the document is saved, you should have unique id assigned to it in the database item or at least some marker so the program should know where to find it later. By looking at your code I assume that the Material "link= file" is suppose to be the link to your file on the file system or the binary data of the file itself. When you construct the HTML table, if the filed is link bind it to a button so  will trigger "/download/<link>" url. Then if the url is like /download/myfile.txt the program should open the file from the file system and make a response with it.